# Listview with edittext crash when exiting and reentering application

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

I have a Listfragment inside a viewpager, the fragment is just containing

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.e("Starter", "Starter");
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat, container, false);

    text = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.text);


    return v;

}
```

And the chat.xml file contains

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="45dp" >
</ListView>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine" >
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="Send" />
```

I can press the EditText and the keyboard comes up, and if I press the back button it disappears.
The listview changes size when the keyboard comes up, or goes down.

All of this works great, until I press the home button, wait a second or two, and then entering the application again. Then I get the following errors:

I don't have any bitmaps in the list, or anything that should cause this error. 
It all works until you exit the application, reenter, and then click the EditText.

If someone have any idea why this it happening it would be great to hear from you!

---

```
04-13 14:02:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(19976): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-13 14:02:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(19976): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot draw recycled bitmaps
04-13 14:02:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(19976):    at android.view.GLES20Canvas.drawBitmap(GLES20Canvas.java:797)
04-13 14:02:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(19976):    at android.view.GLES20RecordingCanvas.drawBitmap(GLES20RecordingCanvas.java:117)
04-13 14:02:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(19976):    at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:393)
04-13 14:02:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(19976):    at android.widget.ImageView.onDraw(ImageView.java:1095)
04-13 14:02:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(19976):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13553)
04-13 14:02:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(19976):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12504)
04-13 14:02:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(19976):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12548)
04-13 14:02:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(19976):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13277)
04-13 14:02:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(19976):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2947)
04-13 14:02:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(19976):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2817)
04-13 14:02:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(19976):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12502)
04-13 14:02:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(19976):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12548)
04-13 14:02:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(19976):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13277)
04-13 14:02:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(19976):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2947)
04-13 14:02:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(19976):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2817)
04-13 14:02:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(19976):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13556)
04-13 14:02:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(19976):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:467)
04-13 14:02:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(19976):    at android.widget.ScrollView.draw(ScrollView.java:1562)
04-13 14:02:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(19976):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12504)
04-13 14:02:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(19976):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12548)
04-13 14:02:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(19976):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13277)
04-13 14:02:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(19976):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2947)
04-13 14:02:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(19976):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2817)
04-13 14:02:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(19976):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12502)
04-13 14:02:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(19976):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12548)
04-13 14:02:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(19976):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13277)
04-13 14:02:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(19976):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2947)
04-13 14:02:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(19976):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2817)
04-13 14:02:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(19976):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12502)
04-13 14:02:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(19976):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12548)
04-13 14:02:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(19976):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2929)
04-13 14:02:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(19976):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12440)
04-13 14:02:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(19976):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12548)
04-13 14:02:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(19976):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2929)
04-13 14:02:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(19976):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12440)
04-13 14:02:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(19976):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12548)
04-13 14:02:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(19976):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2929)
04-13 14:02:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(19976):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12440)
04-13 14:02:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(19976):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12548)
04-13 14:02:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(19976):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2929)
04-13 14:02:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(19976):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12440)
04-13 14:02:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(19976):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12548)
04-13 14:02:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(19976):    at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.draw(HardwareRenderer.java:1170)
04-13 14:02:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(19976):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2432)
04-13 14:02:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(19976):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2286)
04-13 14:02:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(19976):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2053)
04-13 14:02:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(19976):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1151)
04-13 14:02:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(19976):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4661)
04-13 14:02:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(19976):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
04-13 14:02:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(19976):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
04-13 14:02:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(19976):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
04-13 14:02:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(19976):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
04-13 14:02:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(19976):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
04-13 14:02:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(19976):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-13 14:02:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(19976):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
04-13 14:02:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(19976):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5493)
04-13 14:02:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(19976):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-13 14:02:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(19976):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-13 14:02:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(19976):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
04-13 14:02:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(19976):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:795)
04-13 14:02:06.121: E/AndroidRuntime(19976):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: the exception says you are trying to use bitmap which is recycled.

Comment: I know, but I don't have any bitmaps in my code...

Comment: do you have backgrounds set for the layouts somewhere?

Comment: No, just default white

Comment: When I reenter the application, and then press the EditText the keyboard just manages to be display, then I get the error you see above.